# access control via pre-signed url

Tags: amazon-s3, storage, openstack, openstack-swift, ovh

My media storage is Openstack object storage (swift) in the cloud (OVH).

Regarding the user-rights on the uploaded media:

- Images [A] are viewable by all users, but only deletable by
  user-owner/ uploader.
- Images [B] are very private. CRUD by user-owner/ uploader and
  viewable by some other users.

I looked around for solutions and came across [pre-signed (temporary) urls.](https://docs.openstack.org/icehouse/config-reference/content/object-storage-tempurl.html), see also [this article.](https://blog.fyle.in/sharing-files-using-s3-pre-signed-urls-e05d4603e067)

I was wondering whether this provides an acceptable security level. An alternative I could think of is authenticating all users via openstack's authentication module, [Keystone](https://docs.openstack.org/keystone/latest/). But maybe that's just completely stupid and/ or overkill. I started to look in that direction as it might be similar to [AWS S3 use of IAM policies](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/writing-iam-policies-how-to-grant-access-to-an-amazon-s3-bucket/).

My questions:

1. Is the pre-signed url solution the way to go? And if not why not?
2. How would processing images (creating thumbnails) look like? You
   grab it from the storage, process and store it back and delete local
   versions, I suppose?